# Unable to enable modrewrite on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-15.04

I'm using ubuntu 15.04 on my desktop. I have installed lamp, but I'm unable to enable mod rewrite. I have tried by following with terminal :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I also have changed to

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/ooo-default.conf
```

like following:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? rewrite directives cause 500 errors? rewrite not working properly?

Comment: Yeah, rewrite not working properly.  When I run    sudo a2enmod rewrite    my apache2 modrewrite become enable. But when I tried WordPress on my localhost by changing permalink, It doesn't work and show page not found. Thanks. Plz, help

Comment: then you'd need to check if .htaccess is enabled. changing it at /var/www/html is ok, but it can be DISABLED at lower directories as well.

Comment: I have no .htaccess file in www directory nor in html directory. How can I do.

Comment: then where are the rewrites required for wordpress?

Comment: usually it be like following : /var/www/html/.htaccess

Comment: But there is an problem, when I will install mutiple wordpress project, in such away i need multiple .htaccess